# Is it possible to use the Central limit theorem for standard Cauchy distribution?

Tags: probability

I have a simple question about CTL (Central limit theorem)

Is it possible to use the Central limit theorem for standard Cauchy distribution?

I think that it´s not possible because the Mean of the standard Cauchy distribution is undefined and the variance it´s the same.

Is it true??

Thanks for your help, have a nice day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be independent identically distributed standard Cauchy random variables. Then $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}$ has standard Cauchy distribution. So the Central Limit Theorem fails spectacularly.

Comment: Yes, It´s was funny hehe the best answer, thanks you very much